# Retrieve config data from HC Vault in Scala

Tags: scala, hashicorp-vault

I am using below code to read config data from HC Vault,

```
package com.dell.eventreader.config
import com.bettercloud.vault.json.Json
import com.bettercloud.vault.{Vault, VaultConfig}

object VaultConfig {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  
    // Configuration properties
    val host = "vault.com"
    val port = 443
    val scheme = "https"
    val namespace = "my/namespace/path/"
    val roleId = "sample-role"
    val secretId = "sample-secret"

    // Initialize Vault configuration
    val vaultConfig = new VaultConfig()
      .address(s"$scheme://$host:$port")
      .nameSpace(namespace)
      .build()

    // Create a Vault client
    val vault = new Vault(vaultConfig)

    // Specify the path to the secret in Vault
    val secretPath = "/kv/data/scala-poc"

    // Authenticate using role ID and secret ID
    vault.auth().loginByAppRole(roleId, secretId)

    // Read the secret from Vault
    val response = vault.logical().read(secretPath)

    // Extract the configuration from the response
    val configMap = response.getData

    println("Retrieved configuration from Vault:")
    configMap.forEach((key, value) => println(s"$key -> $value"))
  }
}
```

There is no error, but it does not print any config data either. However, there are some config data as I can see from Vault UI. There, the navigation goes like -
*namespace-path -> kv -> scala-poc*

As there is no error shown, I suppose the Vault configurations are correct and have been set correctly as well.
I am unsure of what will be the correct `secretPath` if not this one. Tried with `/kv/scala-poc` as well, but no luck. Also, I don't find anything to set `kv` as backend here.

Unable to identify what's missing in here.

Comment: Maybe share a screenshot (blur it if needed) of what you see in Vault? It's not clear to me what you describe in terms of navigation.

Comment: Updated my question. It's just the path to the namespace. Inside that, I see the list of secret engines, out which 'kv/' is what I'll need to go into. My secret, scala-poc resides under the same.

Comment: A mount point of `kv` implies version 1 of the KV secrets engine, but an immediate path of `data` implies version 2 of the KV secrets engine. Which version is being used? Have you verified both the mount point and the `data` path with either the Vault CLI or API? Additionally empty output to `stdout` would imply no KV pairs in the secret path, which would imply the secret is currently empty.

Comment: As I can confirm, version 2 is being used this side.

Comment: Also, I am able to see in the Vault UI, that config data are present there!